# Apache: a better way to proxy traffic on many different ports to the same ports on another server

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

What is the simplest way to configure apache 2.2 to listen on, say, 20 different ports and then proxy those requests to the same ports on another server?  For example, a request to `http://myserver.com:1000/` should be proxy-forwarded to `http://otherserver.com:1000/`, a request to `http://myserver.com:1001/` should be proxy-forwarded to `http://otherserver.com:1001/`, and so on, for ports 1000 through 1019.

Getting my server to listen on 20 different ports is easily done with 20 `Listen` directives.  The trouble is the proxy directives.  The `mod_proxy` module's `ProxyPass` directive doesn't seem to have a place for any reference to the port number.  I can make 20 different `VirtualHost` sections and put proxy directives in each one:

```
<VirtualHost *:1000>
  ProxyPass        / http://otherserver.com:1000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://otherserver.com:1000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:1001>
  ProxyPass        / http://otherserver.com:1001/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://otherserver.com:1001/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:1002>
  ProxyPass        / http://otherserver.com:1002/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://otherserver.com:1002/
</VirtualHost>

...
```

but that seems extremely tedious.  Though I can generate all those blocks programmatically from a template, I have to believe there's a better way, maybe with a single `mod_rewrite` rule or something?  Suggestions?

Comment: The `<VirtualHost>`s are tedious, but the `Listen`s weren't?  I don't think there's gonna be any 'smooth' way to do this with Apache, unfortunately.. it's not really built for bulk port listeners.

Comment: The `Listen`s were one line each, vs. at least 4 lines for the VirtualHost sections.  I was looking for a one-liner like `RewriteRule (.*) http://otherserver.com:%{REQUEST_PORT}$1` or similar (but one that actually works :)  If it's really not possible to do this in significantly fewer lines, then type that up as an answer and I'll accept it after I've given up hope of better answers :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better served by using "rinetd", which is a TCP connection forwarder.

This is introduced & documented  here:

- http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/601

Answer (score -1):

Make a script to write your config.

Comment: Like I said, I can generate the config programmatically (and I am actually doing so with a Puppet template).  I'm just wondering if there's a simpler solution.